# Why is $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\cos x}dx$ not zero?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\cos x}dx$$

In this, first I replace $x$ with $2\pi -x$.
$$ I = \pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}$$ After that I thought that both limits $0$ and $2\pi$ are the same angle for cosine so integration should be zero.

Comment: I don't understand (at a linguistic level) the last line, but the result of the first line is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2\pi\cos y}{1+\cos y}-\frac{y\cos y}{1+\cos y}\,dy$$ Is it what you get?

Comment: By the way, are you sure your function is integrable in a neighborhood of $\pi$ ? Where did you see this integral ?

Comment: yes , now the limits are same

Comment: @hey: this integral is divergent ... you should check this before anything else

Comment: @M.Boyet it is written in my textbook

Comment: @Adren so how to proceed.

Comment: @hey: Okay, I will write it as a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asked to evaluate the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\cos x}dx$ and this question comes from a textbook ...

IMHO, there are two options :

- this is merely an error, and this happens sometimes, even in good textbooks
- the author of the questions wants you to answer that it is not possible to evaluate the given integral, since it is a divergent one !

Here is why ...

The denominator $1+\cos(x)$ vanishes at $x=\pi$ and so, the convergence of this integral would mean the convergence of :

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\cos x}dx\quad\color{red}{\textrm{ and }}\quad\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\cos x}dx$$

But both diverge, because :

$$\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\underset{x\to\pi}{\sim}\frac{-\pi}{1-\cos(x-\pi)}\underset{x\to\pi}{\sim}\frac{-2\pi}{(x-\pi)^2}$$

[ The last equivalence comes from $\cos(h)\underset{h\to0}{=}1-\frac{h^2}{2}+o(h^2)$ ]

and we know that $\displaystyle{\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^\alpha}}$ converges iff $\alpha<1$.

---

That said, it would be interesting to compute :

$$A=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx$$

which is well defined !

And the answer is $\displaystyle{A=\frac{\pi^2}8-\frac\pi2+\ln(2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

No, since $x$ is also replaced by $2x-\pi$. So you get
$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{2\pi\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}-I$$

And $$I = \pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}$$

Comment: Be careful ! This integral does *not* converge ... since $\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\underset{\pi}{\sim}-\frac{2}{(x-\pi)^2}$.

Comment: Yes, I pointed that fact in a comment above ;)